# WCF JSON Service not exposing methods

Tags: .net, json, wcf

I am trying to create a WCF Service that returns a JSON Object.  My first problem is that I am not seeing the service method exposed to even call it.  When I call the service method like this... "http://localhost:60090/VehicleDataService/detailbydivision?divisionId=1&year=2012", I get a 404 error.

Web.Config....

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="GMEOG.VehicleDataService" behaviorConfiguration="metadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="GMEOG.IVehicleDataService" behaviorConfiguration="VehicleDataServiceBehavior">
          <identity>
            <dns value="" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="metadataBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="VehicleDataServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Here is my Interface....

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "GMEOG.VehicleDataService", Name = "VehicleDataService")]
public interface IVehicleDataService

{
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse,
           UriTemplate = "DetailByDivision?divisionId={divisionId}&year={year}")]
[return: MessageParameter(Name = "Vehicle")]
List<Vehicle> DetailByDivision(string divisionId, string year);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining your service file? Using a .svc file or using routing?

If the former (assuming a svc file called "VehicleDataService.svc"), the address should be `http://localhost:60090/VehicleDataService`**.svc**`/detailbydivision?divisionId=1&year=2012`.

If the latter, please update your post how you're using the routing service.

If something else, please state on the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Host to your service endpoint in web.config:

```
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:60090/VehicleDataService" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.  I still get the same results.